# JavaScript split slice join

Tags: javascript, join, split, native

Кто может подсказать что конкретно находится под капотом функций split, slice, join?

Это:

```js
console.log("".split.toLocaleString())
console.log("".slice.toLocaleString())
console.log([].join.toLocaleString())
```

говорит о том, что это всё нативный код.

Гугл выкидывает только стандартные доки из разряда "как этим пользоваться", но меня интересует не это.

Comment: Там сишный (или какой там) код. А что Вы ожидали?

Comment: @Other а где его посмотреть ?

Comment: @stack-it Вряд ли ты где-то найдешь нативный код, более я того думаю он отличается в зависимости от интерпритатора.

Comment: @stack-it А к чему такой интерес именно к этим методам?

Comment: @UladzislauKaminski интерес не к ним. стало интересно , как вообще можно посмотреть на реализацию, но понял, что у всех браузеров она своя и закрытая к тому же

Comment: @stack-it то что компилируется в машинный код сложно декомпилировать, например java компилируется в байткод и ее проще декомпилировать и посмотреть исходники, если интересно конечно

Comment: @NetScum. Посмотреть реализацию можно, поковырявшись в исходниках того же V8, к примеру ) Только зачем???

Comment: Реализация открытая. Исходники gecko и v8 доступны…

Comment: @stack-it, любая open-source-имплементация стандарта ES. [Blink](https://github.com/ChromiumWebApps/blink), например.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы.

Comment: @Sublihim, ну надо.) Очень интересно как это работает под капотом. В часности, не так давно один скриптер выдал код со словами "я не использую тут циклов во избежание накладных расходов". А у меня, вот, пятая точка чует, что под капотом всё равно где-то работают циклы.

Comment: @Other, что его реализацию можно посмотреть.))0 К тому же C я знаю. А вот asm не очень... За Blink благодарю.

Comment: @Sublihim, чтобы хорошо понимать как это работает.

Comment: @NetScum, интересно, вы посмотрите реализацию, к примеру `join` увидите, что там циклы, к примеру. И что же дальше? Вы откажетесь писать на js? Т.е. с одной стороны это похвально знать, как это работает, а с другой стороны - здравствуй паранойя.

Comment: @Other. Blink - это движок для рендеринга html. Вряд ли он поможет разобраться с JS :)

Comment: @Sublihim, конечно же Вы правы. Думал о V8, но написал Blink. Впрочем, истина где-то рядом :)